# Store object inside object and update

Tags: javascript

I am trying to store an array inside and object like this:

```
var fieldData = {
   checkedItem: {
      fieldID : “1234”,
      SelectedFields : []
   } 
   checkedItem: {
      fieldID : “12345”,
      SelectedFields : []
   } 
}
```

I then want to also replace all selected fields to this object at a later stage.

I am a newbie to this so not sure how it would be done, I have tried everything I can think of!

The later changes to the object will referenced by fieldID.

I have tried stuff like:

```
fieldData["fieldID"] = selectedFieldSeq;

fieldData[selectedFieldSeq]["SelectedFields"] = $('#Tree').jqxTree('getCheckedItems');
```

$('#Tree').jqxTree('getCheckedItems');

returns an array of checked items on my tree.

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

'fieldID = $('#Tree').jqxTree('getCheckedItems');'
'fieldData.SelectedFields = fieldID'

Comment: hmm, perhaps my object is wrong, There will be multiple fieldID's with there own set of SelectedFields

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with this line :

```
fieldData[selectedFieldSeq]["SelectedFields"]
```

`fieldData[selectedFieldSeq]` is not defined, so it's return `undefined`

You need to initialize it before using it :

```
if (!fieldData[selectedFieldSeq]) {
    fieldData[selectedFieldSeq] = {
        SelectedFields : []
    };
}
```

After, you can assign some value to `SelectedFields`.

Or did you want to simply do this : `fieldData.SelectedFields = ...;` ?